# Can I treat a multi-dimensional array as a one-dimensional array?

Tags: c

I need to write a function which can take any two-dimensional array of a given element type. The C program below illustrates my current approach. Is it well-defined?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LEN(arr) (sizeof (arr) / sizeof (arr)[0])

static void Print(const int *A, int m, int n)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%d ", A[i * n + j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int A[2][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};

    Print((int *) A, LEN(A), LEN(A[0]));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works only for int arrays. Was that intended?

Comment: @QuasselKasper Yes, but it could be some other type. It's fixed however.

Comment: Side note: the result of the `sizeof` operator is `size_t`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior of the code you show is not defined by the C standard for two reasons. One, it violates the rules about pointer conversion. Two, it violates the rules about pointer arithmetic.

First, consider `(int *) A` in the call to `Print`. In this code, the array `A` is automatically converted to a pointer to its first member, which is an array of 3 `int`. This conversion is permitted by C 2011 [N1570] clause 6.3.2.3, paragraph 7, which says “A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined. Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.” However, this is all the standard says about the converted pointer. When you use the pointer in `Print`, in the expression `A[i * n + j]`, the behavior is not defined because nothing in the C standard tells us what this converted pointer is, other than that it can be converted back to the original type. Although the pointer was converted to an `int *`, we do not know that the result of the conversion is actually a usable pointer to the `int` that is `A[0][0]`.

Second, even if this pointer were a valid pointer to `A[0][0]`, the standard does not define what the behavior is when you use it to index beyond the array of 3 `int`. In the expression `A[i * n + j]`, the subscript expression is defined to be equivalent to `*((A) + (i * n + j)` by 6.5.2.1 2. When `i * n + j` is added to `A`, the semantics is governed by 6.5.6 8, which says that pointer arithmetic can be used to add to or subtract from a pointer as long as the result points to another element in the same array or to one beyond the last element. If you have a pointer to the first `int` of an array of 3 `int` and you add enough to move the pointer into the next array of 3 `int`, you have gone beyond the limit, and the behavior is undefined. (Since it is legal to point one past the last element, you can add 3 to a pointer to `A[0][0]` to get a pointer to one beyond `A[0][2]`, but you are not allowed to apply `*` to this pointer, because the paragraph says “If the result points one past the last element of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary * operator that is evaluated.”)

That said, some C implementation will support these pointer conversions and this arithmetic. But the code is not portable; it is not strictly conforming C code.

Comment: This is quite interesting! Is there any known C implementation that August Karlstrom's approach would not work?

Comment: @sg7: You should do some research what modern highly optimising compilers like gcc or clang do to such code. **Never ever** invoke undefined behaviour or exploit casts.

Comment: @Olaf I tried few, I could not find one which would produce wrong result.

Comment: @sg7: So just because three times speed driving at 200km/h through a town did not cause an accident does mean it is safe?

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. Does this mean that there is no portable solution in C to this problem?

Comment: As mentioned by sg7, it would be interesting to know if there is any known compiler for which the code would fail.

Comment: @sg7: It is difficult to know when breaking the rules will result in a penalty. In this case, I would suspect that a longer subarray would break on systems with memory segment addressing. In such systems, addresses are composed of a base and an offset. In a C implementation for such a system, adding to a pointer to an `int` in an array tnat fits within the offset range might add only to the offset, so it would wrap, and hence fail, when the addition goes beyond the offset field. Adding to a pointer to a large array of `int` would adjust both the base and the offset.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom: It is not even guaranteed that array will reside somewhere in memory. Modern compilers do a lot of optimisations, including replacing standard library functions by other, faster functions. For example gcc typically `printf` by `puts` for certain situations. Read about the "as-if" rule. The actual question is **why you don't want to use the correct way and pass the 2D array to your function** (resp. a pointer to a 1D array) and let the compiler do the 2D indexing. To me it is an XY problem and not good C..

Comment: @Olaf "why you don't want to use the correct way and pass the 2D array to your function" - because in C there is no way to define a function which can receive a N-dimensional array of any size (in all dimensions).

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom: C has a (now optional to the implementation) feature of variable length arrays. The number of dimensions cannot vary, but the dimensions can. For example, you can declare a function `void foo(int a, int b, int c, float G[a][b][c])`.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom: Well, this is a _brand new_ feature, just introduced 18 years ago with C99 **mandatorily**. It was made optional against the commitee's policy with C11, but every modern compiler supports it. To be exact: you cannot pass an array to/from a function at all in C. But you can pass a pointer to a 1D array as I wrote already.

Comment: @Olaf If you want full portability C89 is still king: "Most C compilers provide support for at least some of the features introduced in C99." - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99#Implementations

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom: Some people moved on and left the 1980ies. It is people sticking to ancient implementations who made the bad reputation of C and let compiler vendors stick to old BS. All modern compilers do support at last C99, most C11 since some years. Sidenote: wikipedia is not a reliable reference. And you should differentiate between the C language and the standard library. A freestanding implementation needs to provide only very few headers, no code parts of the stdlib.

Answer (score -2):

It is well defined, just in the invocation use it like this:

```
Print((int *) A, 2, 3);
```

You only need to give your method the number of rows and number of columns, instead of pass the numbers of elements and the size of each element in bytes.

Because at compilation time it knows you are talking about `int`, so when you ask for the element at position `[i * n + j]` it already knows you are in an `int *` then add the number of bytes of `int` for you.

Comment: The behavior is not defined because the pointer conversion is not defined except by C 2011 [N1570] 6.3.2.3 7 for limited use and because the array indexing violates 6.5.6 8.

Answer (score -3):

In C language arrays are always laid out contiguously in memory:

```
int A[2][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
```

In memory looks like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

exactly the same as:

```
int A[6] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
```

Your approach is appropriate.

Edit:

There are some interesting theoretical arguments against the validity of this approach base on the pointer arithmetics. Yet, it seems to me that it would be quite hard to construct a compiler which on one hand has to conform to 3.1.2.5 and could not resolve the pointer arithmetics for objects of the same type/size.
It may mean nothing but I shell mention the code compiled and run properly on:

```
GCC 4.6.3;  GCC 5.3.0; GCC 5.4.0; GCC 6.3; C99 Strict GCC 6.3; Zapcc 5.0.0; GCC 7.1.1;
GCC 7.2.0; clang 3.8.0; gcc 5.0.4
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23506 for x64;
```

For what is worth, I have not encountered a compiler which would had difficulties with `August Karlstrom's` code.

Comment: Maybe a reference to 3.1.2.5 Types

"An array type describes a contiguously allocated set of objects with a particular member object type, called the element type ."

Comment: The fact that an array is laid out contiguously in memory does not mean the rules of C allow you to address elements of one subarray using a pointer to elements in another.

Comment: Although this is practically possible, it violates the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: This answer is wrong, the code is illegal. It violated the effective type (aka strict aliasing) rule. Modern compilers are well known to strictly follow the standard when optimising, hence this can very well result in a completely broken program. See the answer by @EricPostpischil for a correct description.